# Wiring for grounds wire in light fixture

Tags: light-fixture

Im not sure how to connect these ground wires. Theres a ground wire connected to green screw on electrical box, and theres another green screw on the light fixture bracket. Thanks

[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGDvl.jpg[image][image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a strange ground clip on the electrical box. The box doesn't appear to be metal and that clip will interfere with your fixture bracket. I would remove that clip from the box and pigtail those two grounds to a 6" piece of bare copper wire. Install your bracket. Wrap your extended ground wire around the green screw on the bracket. Connect the end of the extended ground wire to the ground wire from the fixture with a small wire nut.

Comment: I agree that the ground screw looks like it would foul the fixture bracket, however, it does look like its a (heavily) painted metal box, because that flat piece that the ground screw is attached to looks way to thin for it to be a plastic box. I do agree with your recommendation to pig tail the grounds. It looks like the ground wire goes _near_ the ground screw in the box, then continues on. I'd investigate further to see where it goes. I'd also carefully/gently scrape some of the paint off the wires just to make them easier to identify. (Don't damage the insulation!)\

Comment: @FreeMan  That had me puzzled too but the mounting screw on the top and the widening on the left just looked like nonmetal. The ground wires looked like two shepard hooks (poorly) , one almost out. At least two cables so two grounds. :-)

Comment: Ah, yes, the 2 rounded parts going from the opening toward the back do look like the fixture-screw mounts on a plastic box and that thin piece with the ground screw looks like an add-on piece of metal... Darn painters!

Comment: I remember seeing those “clips” or adapter plates on round boxes to allow different sizes of shell covers but I haven’t seen them since the concentric ring plate adapters became popular. Those adapters work on both metal and plastic that looks like a brown fiber box to me. Look at the ring adapter above and realize that will fit with any box the clip or plate won’t center the shell as well probably why we don’t see them any more.

Comment: I wonder if that tab on the box is there to bond some type of integrated metal spreader bar or some type of metallic support of an old work box? Rather than immediately abandoning that connection I would first try to flatten the surface plane by unwrapping the existing ground so the wire doesn't overlap where it exceeds 360º.  The green screw on the adapter and the bare from the light assembly need to be pigtailed to the ground wires in the box.

Comment: Thank you all. @Jack. I think whoever installed this was really cheap that they didnt want to install a bracket bar so they used that small metal piece. 

This electrical box is strictly prewire for pendant lights over an island. I can control the light from multiple locations and thats why there are two black, two white and two ground wires. Is it common to have one of the ground wire connected to the screw and other one hanging?

Comment: @J4mes  No, it not common and not allowed. All grounds have to be connected together. In this case pigtail the two grounds with a 6" piece of bare wire and loop that wire around the bracket screw and hook the end of it to the ground from the light. Use a wire nut.